# How do I use sp_send_dbmail to send the content of a VARBINARY column?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sp-send-dbmail

I have some files stored in a SQL Server 2005 table in a `VARBINARY(MAX)` column. I need to email these files to users on a schedule, and though I can write a C# service to extract and send the email `sp_send_dbmail` would seem to be perfect for my purpose. The code I'm using looks like this:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'SQL Mail Profile',
@recipients = 'emailaddress',
@query = 'set nocount on; select CAST(content AS varchar(MAX)) from files where fileid=''xxx''' ,
@subject = 'Random File',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'random file.pdf',
@query_result_no_padding = 1,
@query_result_header = 0,
@query_no_truncate = 1;
```

When I use the query directly I get the text representation of the PDF file out, but when I use the code above I get a truncated version of the file (always 792 bytes). This would seem to suggest that there is a setting somewhere that controls this, but although I can find settings that control document size they are all way bigger than the file I'm trying to mail!

Anyone seen this before, or have any ideas where to look?

Comment: You should probably include specifically which settings you have already checked so that people know which things to discount.

Answer (score 1):

The following tutorial may touch on something that you've missed: http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1438